# Sudden error: No static method setWebDialogTheme(I)V

Tags: java, android, facebook

Someone already asked this question but was put on hold so I thought I'd try. We both had the same problem at about the same time so I was wondering if it was possibly a problem with Facebook Sdk?

Or I possibly did something but it felt like this error came out of no where and can no longer login to Facebook using the app I making.

Anyway, the error is

On the `FacebookProvider.java` file, the `FacebookSdk.setWebDialogTheme(theme)`; has the `setWebDialogTheme` part in red. This is a read-only file so I don't think I could have accidentally changed it.

The error message is:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: gospa.hugomatica.com.gospa, PID: 3578
>                                                                             java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setWebDialogTheme(I)V in
>   class Lcom/facebook/FacebookSdk; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.facebook.FacebookSdk' appears in
>   /data/app/ga.matica.com.ga-_n-bcJLql8g_mU0q1hjX8g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.provider.FacebookProvider.(FacebookProvider.java:67)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.util.signincontainer.IdpSignInContainer.onCreate(IdpSignInContainer.java:124)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2329)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 09-28
>   10:02:52.889 3578-3578/gospa.hugomatica.com.gospa E/UncaughtException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setWebDialogTheme(I)V in
>   class Lcom/facebook/FacebookSdk; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.facebook.FacebookSdk' appears in
>   /data/app/ga.matica.com.ga-_n-bcJLql8g_mU0q1hjX8g==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.provider.FacebookProvider.(FacebookProvider.java:67)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.firebase.ui.auth.util.signincontainer.IdpSignInContainer.onCreate(IdpSignInContainer.java:124)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2329)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Sorry,if I didn't format correctly, new to stack overflow

Comment: I've just had this issue too. Seems like an update to the sdk broke the FacebookProvider class.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** FirebaseUI has been updated to fix this issue. There should be no problems now.

The latest update to the Facebook SDK for android moved the [set|get]WebDialogTheme methods to a different class. FirebaseUI needs to be updated accordingly upstream.

Source : [Facebook SDK Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x)

Relevant text from source:

> Moves FacebookSDK.[set|get]WebDialogTheme(...) to WebDialog.[set|get]WebDialogTheme(...)

You may try using either an older version of the Facebook SDK, or wait for FirebaseUI to incorporate the appropriate change.

Comment: this fixed it for me
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' =>
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'

Comment: It is supposed to be fixed in Firebase-Android-UI 3.0.0 but I am still seeing this issue with Facebook SDK 4.27.0 https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/929 https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/976

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was to go back to an earlier version of FB: 
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
4.26.0 somehow did not work for me when Syncing and 4.27 is the new version mentioned in the previous answer.

all FB versions available at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads